# Is there a way to run scripts when someone is answering to a Google Form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

So, here at the company I work for we usually manage the workforce weekends schedules in a very manual way using Excel, and then upload a pdf version of the sheet in our intranet so everyone can see their own schedule for the rest of the month and look up for swaps if they need to.

The problem is that the workforce recently has grown up a lot and we're spending a lot of time validating and reuploading the schedule everytime we need to do the shift swaps. So I decided to start a project using Google Sheets and Google Forms, so we could just show iFrame of the sheet in the view mode, and their supervisors could make their swaps via a google form, which would update the sheet and they could see it happening on-the-fly, I guess.

Now that I gave you some context, what I really need is to discover if there's actually a way to accomplish what I'm trying to, because I already stuck once realizing that the script running from a Google Sheet only works with edit permissions (I need to no one have permission to change manually the sheet and preferably not even needing to link account to Google), but now I realized even when scripting inside of the form it doesn't run when people are answering to the form, but only in the edit mode, which I think it's useless for me since questions should be dynamic (the form would look for the available weekends and employees in the sheet using some validations).

For example, the code below runs when I open the form in Edit mode, but not when I open the shared link:

```
function onOpen() {
 var ui = FormApp.getUi();
  ui.alert('test');
}
```

So, my question is if this project is possible using Google Scripts and the suite, if there's some kind of option or permission I'm missing to make it work, or if it's worth I try to do it using an not inbound countainer script, or maybe HTML Service, or if I should forget Google and look for another tools for this job.

Thanks.

Comment: No, there is no way to have code run when someone is filling out the Google Form.

Comment: Oh, what a shame. Lost a couple days into this. But thanks for the answer! I'll try to look another way to have this project going forward!

Comment: Server code can interact with a form written as a web app. Checkout google.script.run.

Comment: The workflow you had in mind is indeed not feasible but that doesn't mean you can not take advantage of Google's services. Use HTML to write your own form and you'll be able to do whatever you want.

Comment: You can write code to update the form when a response is submitted via an `onFormSubmit` trigger, but this approach is only effective if you can guarantee that respondents don't interact with the form at the same time.

Comment: Hey people, thank you all for your patience and I'm already looking into the HTML Service and how to deploy the script as a web app. I think the onFormSubmit method can't do everything I need but I'll surely use it to update some log information.